# relationship choices¶widget showing text

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, widget, django-widget

I would like to display choices of Test_Baustoff->art Model in my Test_Objekt Model Form.

Right now i am trying to solve it with a Widget...

Models:

```
class Test_Objekt(models.Model):
   baustoffid = models.ForeignKey(Test_Baustoff, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   bezeichnung = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)

class Test_Baustoff(models.Model):
   art = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   wert = models.IntegerField(default='0')
```

Forms: (found this code in the django docs... don't know if i am using it in the right way??)

```
class BaustoffidSelect(forms.Select):
    def create_option(self, name, value, label, selected, index, subindex=None, attrs=None):
        option = super().create_option(name, value, label, selected, index, subindex, attrs)
        if value:
            option['attrs']['data-art'] = value.instance.art
        return option

class ObjektForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
        model = Test_Objekt
        fields = ['bezeichnung', 'baustoffid', 'bauweiseid', 'dickeaussenwand', 'dickedaemmung', 'fensterqualitaet']
        labels = {'bezeichnung': 'Objekt-Bez'}
        widgets = {'baustoffid': BaustoffidSelect}
```

html template:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-light">
        {{objekt_form.as_table}}
    </table>
```

For the moment, I don't find a way to solve my problem. I looked some tutorials or StackOverflow questions but nothing up to now.

Do you have any idea about this handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a list of tuples with model object instances:

```
Baustoff_choices = []
for i in Test_Baustoff.objects.all():
    Baustoff_choices.append(
        (i.id,i.art)
    ) #second element is what is this what will be displayed in template
```

Then in your forms.ModelForm:

```
baustoffid = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Baustoff_choices)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh Thanks a lot. This works fine with the **id!**

I was already trying this approach but made the mistake that i wanted to implement this into my **models**...  I did not know that i can also add a extra field to my **forms.modelform**

what i was asking myself.
is it also possible to not save the **id** but a **foreykn key object**

**like in models:**

```
  #baustoffid = models.ForeignKey(Test_Baustoff, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**and in forms:**

```
for i in Test_Baustoff.objects.all():
    Baustoff_choices.append(
        (**i**, i.art) # or somithing like **i.instance**
    )
```

but i get:
Cannot assign "'Test_Bauweise object (2)'": "Test_Objekt.bauweiseid" must be a "Test_Bauweise" instance.

kind regards!

Comment: You want to create a new assigned `Test_Objekt` when someone choose one of your `Test_Baustoff`?

Comment: yes kind of.  when i use a foreignkey field in my forms, i can choose from the foreign key objects, but the user only gets shown **-Object(1) -Object(2)** in the html file.  what i want to do is, that the user can choose from `Test_Baustoff.art`, and after the user hast chosen i want to work with the Object corresponding to the `.art` field. you get me ?

Comment: solved. missed to add this function in my models.py so it got displeyed like "Object(1)"...

def __str__(self): return self.art

Answer (score 0):

solved.
missed to add this function in my models.py
so it got displeyed like "Object(1)"...

`def __str__(self): return self.art`